# Android Studio and Git - How do I GPG-sign my commits?

Tags: windows, git, android-studio, github, gnupg

According to [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/), I simply need to include the `-S` switch to sign my commit using my GPG key, but I don't see how I can use that in Android Studio.

How do I sign my commits in Android Studio?

**EDIT:** I appreciate that OSX solutions are coming along, but I'd really like to see an answer that works with Windows. <sub><sup>I only use my Mac for documents and stuff.</sup></sub>

Comment: Hopefully someone comes along with a Windows solution.

Comment: My answer is for Windows as well: test the first workarounds, and if they are not enough, I will adapt the last one to Windows.

Comment: @VonC I'll test them out later. 12 AM here.

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned in "[Sign git commits with GPG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20628543/6309)", with Git 2.0:

> If you want to GPG sign all your commits, you have to add the -S option all the time.
>   The `commit.gpgsign` config option allows to sign all commits automatically.

This doesn't fully work though, and is [followed by issue 127802](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127802), with the following workarounds:

> Created a helper script with that content:

```
/usr/bin/gpg –batch –no-tty "$@"
```

> and set `gpg.program` to that script

Or:

> Adding "`no-tty`" to "`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`" solved the problem for me.

You might still get the error message:

```
Commit failed with error:
gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Again: bug in progress, also followed by [issue 110261](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261):

> resolve it with this in addition to the previous solution (OS X):
>
> 1) `brew install gnupg gnupg2 pinentry-mac`
>
> 2) `nano ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` -> 
>        `pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac`
>
> 3) `git config -–global gpg.program gpg2`

Comment: Thank you!. On my Mac on OS 10.14.3, all I had to do was the last 3 steps mentioned. Pinentry works when doing a commit through Terminal and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

After make some test I follow this steps and it works
Please remember to restart the Android Studio after follow this steps:

Are you tired off write the password for each commit???

- Follow the link:
  https://github.com/pstadler/keybase-gpg-github
- after that edit the gpg.conf

> nano ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf

## add the following lines

```
use-agent
no-tty
default-key <your key id>
```

- after made all the configuration and if you use MacOS. You should:

> ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.7.0_1  /usr/local/opt/libgcrypt
>
> ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libgpg-error/1.22 /usr/local/opt/libgpg-error
>
> ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libassuan/2.4.2 /usr/local/opt/libassuan
>
> ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pth/2.0.7 /usr/local/opt/pth

- execute

> source ~/.profile

- make one commit using the option -S

> git commit -am "my commit message" -S

- you should get a password promp. 
  -- put your password

Thats it!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have git for Windows installed, and selected MingGW option during setup, this is what I used to get Android Studio working with signing commits.

Programs mentioned/used with links for those who don't have them yet.

- Android Studio 2.2.2
- Gpg4win 2.3.3 (https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html)

  - Using variant *"Gpg4win with GnuPG component only"*
- Git for Windows 2.10.1

For those who wants to read the article I used to get gpg signing working in my Windows environment  (The bottom half of the page starting with the `git config` lines are what we're more concerned with):
https://jamesmckay.net/2016/02/signing-git-commits-with-gpg-on-windows/

I'll briefly walk through the process for doing the gpg portion via command line - presuming that all three programs are installed already from here on in.

#### Check Git setting in Android Studio

If you haven't specified where git is in Android Studio, here's where you do it in Settings:

> NOTE:  This can be done either in `File > Project Settings` for one project or `File > Other Settings > Default Settings...`
>
> *Version Control  >  Git  >  Path to Git Executable*

Since I was using the MinGW version, it's set to:
`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`

#### Export existing public and secret keys from MinGW version (git bash)

NOTE:  Execute using MinGW prompt program

> 1. `gpg --export > ~/gpg-public`
> 2. `gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/gpg-secret`

NOTE: For those who don't know, `~/` is by default set to your user's home directory. (e.g. Windows 10: `C:/Users/%USERNAME%`)

#### Import exported keys into Gpg4win

NOTE:  Execute using Windows Command Prompt.

> 1. `gpg --import < "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/gpg-public"`
> 2. `gpg --import < "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/gpg-secret"`

Replace the location with wherever your `gpg-public` and `gpg-secret` files are.

#### Make git use gpg from Gpg4win

*As mentioned in the article.  It's reposted here if you didn't open it.*

NOTE:  Execute using MinGW prompt program

> - `git config --global gpg.program "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/gpg2.exe"`

Replace the `gpg.program` value (keeping the `gpg2.exe`) above with wherever you specified the gpg4win installer to install it to.

*(OPTIONAL)*  While you're at it, you can configure your git to auto sign your commits with a default key (git version >= 2.0 required)

> - `git config --global user.name <name>`
> - `git config --global user.email <email>`
> - `git config --global user.signingkey <your-key-ID>`
> - `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`

Replace the values in `< >` with your own.  You can get the key ID by running `gpg --list-keys` and taking the ID from the line starting with `pub` and after the `/`.

Now you should be able to commit using Android Studio and see a prompt come up for the password entry.